# Pycharm работа с интерпретаторами

Tags: python, linux, pycharm, venv

Пользуюсь Linux Manjaro.
Всё началось с того, что я хотел настроить flake8 на Pycharm. То есть что бы при запуске нового проекта он и еще несколько постоянно нужных пакетов нужной версии были установлены. Но на сколько я понял изначальный шаблон виртуального окружения virtualvenv менять нельзя и кроме как созданием шаблонного интерпретатора (уже настроенного виртуального окружения с установленными библиотеками) это больше никак не сделать.

Тут всплыл следующий момент. При создании проекта я выбираю опцию "previusly  configured intrpreter" и выбираю нужное окружение, тогда соответственно новое окружение в проекте создано не будет, а всё по умолчанию будет унаследовано от шаблона. И при каких-то индивидуальных изменениях будет изменен и шаблон, что мне не очень хотелось бы.

Так вот, объясните пожалуйста:

- Можно ли редактировать base interpreter что бы там помимо pip, wheel и setuptools изначально были еще нужные мне библиотеки?

Просто если мне не изменяет память, то на windows если устанавливаешь пакеты в системный python, то они же потом наследуются в новое созданное виртуальное окружение.

Comment: У вас в PyCharm есть терминал, верно? В этом терминале python запускается из venv текущего проекта. Установите все необходимые вам пакеты в этот venv через pip. По умолчанию venv создаётся минимальным, на это PyCharm повлияеть не может.

Comment: То что можно через терминал установить это понятно. Просто куча похожих проектов и устанавливать все одно и тоже каждый раз надоедает. А флейк по сути вообще нужен всегда.

Comment: Тогда установите все нужные пакеты в один venv и установите галку Make available to all projects

Comment: Да но тогда если вдруг поверх ещё что-то установить, то оно и туда же ведь установится тоже, а не по ставится отдельно в выбранный проект, вот в чем прикол. А мне эта доп библа в шаблоне не нужна

Comment: План Б. Поставьте отдельно какой-нибудь пайтон, загрузите в него общий набор библиотек, и укажите его дефолтным интерпретатором. При создании venv поставьте галку Inherit global site-packages, тогда в созданный venv скопируются установленные пакеты. При необходимости в каждый venv можно доставить необходимое.

Comment: Вот это звучит как хорошая идея, спасибо, буду пробовать